# Let $x, y \in \Bbb Z$. If $x + y \geq 135$, then $x > 67$ or $y > 67$.

Tags: inequality, integers

Let $x, y \in \Bbb Z$. If $x + y \geq 135$, then $x > 67$ or $y > 67$.

How do I prove this statement? I'm new to proofs, and I find this to be too obvious to prove.

Comment: If it is obvious (and it is) one should be able to explain why it is obvious.

Answer (score 5):

Proof: We are goning to prove that $x>67$ or $y>67$. Now we assume that both $x$ and $y$ satisfy that $x \le 67$ and $y \le 67$. So $x+y \le 67+67<135$. This is a contrddiction.
So we have that $x>67$ or $y>67$.

Answer (score 4):

We need [Proof by contradiction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_by_contradiction)

If both $x,y\le67, x+y\le67+67<135$

Comment: Can you please elaborate/explain? Im fairly new to proofs

Comment: @sam, Please find the link in the answer

Comment: Wish I know the mistake here